# SPARK SQL CASE WHEN > 0

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe

I have been struggling with this for about 3 hours.
Running Spark 1.6

Trying to get this to work in the spark SQl context.  evt_acct_app_id is an integer, why is this not working, in sql this is easy.  I tried multiple variations of this, remove apostrophe and etc.

```
CASE evt_acct_app_id
 WHEN evt_acct_app_id > '0' THEN '001'
 ELSE '002'
 END
 AS EVNT_SUBTYPE_CD,
```

Keep getting this error:Got this unknown exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE evt_acct_app_id WHEN (cast(evt_acct_app_id as double) > cast(0 as double)) THEN 001 ELSE 002' 
due to data type mismatch: key and WHEN expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;
```

Comment: You should remove one of the two `evt_acct_app_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use single quotes if you are comparing to an integer:

```
(CASE WHEN evt_acct_app_id > 0 THEN '001'
      ELSE '002'
 END) as EVNT_SUBTYPE_CD,
```

In addition, when you have expressions for comparison, the correct syntax for `CASE` does not have a column name after the `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

CASE 
 WHEN evt_acct_app_id > '0' THEN '001'
 ELSE '002'
 END
 AS EVNT_SUBTYPE_CD,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def evtChange(d:Column) = {when(d > 0,"001").otherwise("002")}

data.select( evtChange($"evt_acct_app_id").as("EVNT_SUBTYPE_CD") )
```